# PullHookサンプルでの初期読込の追加方法

Tags: onsen-ui

http://ja.onsen.io/guide/overview.html#UsingPullHook
にありますサンプルで初期表示時に、pullhookせずに、スクリプトにて読込を実施するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: プルフックしたとき、どのように動作しているか理解していますか？

Comment: 単純にng-actionでイベントが発生。そして、loadが動作する。と考えています。なので、該当ページなりが表示された時に、loadが動作すれば良いのかなと思っています。
そのイベントが、例えば、ng-click="load()"でも、動作します。
が、該当ページが表示された時に、イベントを発生させる方法がよく分かりません。。。

Answer (score 1):

コントローラ内の`ons.ready()`で取得処理を呼び出します。

```
ons.bootstrap()
    .controller('DemoController', function($scope, $timeout, $http) {
        $scope.items = [];
        ons.ready(function() {
            loadJson(function(){});
        });
        $scope.load = function($done) {
            loadJson($done);
        };
        $scope.reset = function() {
            $scope.items.length = 0;
        };
        function loadJson($done) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $http.jsonp('http://numbersapi.com/random/year?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
                    .success(function(data) {
                        $scope.items.unshift({
                            desc: data,
                            rand: Math.random()
                        });
                    })
                    .error(function() {
                        $scope.items.unshift({
                            desc: 'No data',
                            rand: Math.random()
                        });
                    })
                    .finally(function() {
                        $done();
                    });
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ons.readyもいろいろやってみたのですが、そういう事ですね。
なるほどです。
あとは各ページ用にコントローラーを作ればおkですね。
実験します！

Comment: 予定通り、good jobでした。
助かりました。
★4つ